# Why does ExceptionInInitializerError occur when invoking HtmlCompat in an Android unit test using Robolectric?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, kotlin, robolectric

I am attempting to unit test a method that is part of my use case layer of an Android app. The method receives an XML RSS feed and returns it to the view model as GSON-parsed objects. The testing class is annotated with `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)`.

The test fails because a `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` (among others) is thrown by `.fromHtml()` within this method of the use case class:

```
    private fun convertHtml(rawString: String): String {
    return HtmlCompat
        .fromHtml(rawString, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
        .toString()
        .replace("￼", "")
        .trim()
}
```

In reading the stack trace, it appears that this might be an issue with Robolectric trying to initialize a static method or class? I say this because of some of the lines in the stack trace, such as:

```
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.RobolectricInternals.performStaticInitialization(RobolectricInternals.java:61)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.ShadowWrangler.classInitializing(ShadowWrangler.java:178)
```

Unfortunately, all of my research has gotten me nowhere. I cannot seem to find anything related to this issue. I have seen several threads talk about using Robolectric and PowerMock together for testing static classes, although I am not sure if this is a relevant approach, and I would like to avoid adding more testing frameworks if possible. **Why is this exception being thrown, and how does one address this exception?**

For reference, here is the whole stack trace:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.__constructor__(SpannableStringBuilder.java:61)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.<init>(SpannableStringBuilder.java)
    at android.text.HtmlToSpannedConverter.__constructor__(Html.java:425)
    at android.text.HtmlToSpannedConverter.<init>(Html.java)
    at android.text.Html.fromHtml(Html.java:135)
    at android.text.Html.fromHtml(Html.java:101)
    at androidx.core.text.HtmlCompat.fromHtml(HtmlCompat.java:150)
    at com.domg.testrss.domain.usecase.GetNewsHeadlinesUseCase.convertHtml(GetNewsHeadlinesUseCase.kt:162)
    at com.domg.testrss.domain.usecase.GetNewsHeadlinesUseCase.convertXmlToJson(GetNewsHeadlinesUseCase.kt:80)
    at com.domg.testrss.domain.usecase.GetNewsHeadlinesUseCase.execute(GetNewsHeadlinesUseCase.kt:35)
    at com.domg.testrss.GetNewsHeadlinesUseCaseTest$parsing success$1.invokeSuspend(GetNewsHeadlinesUseCaseTest.kt:33)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:279)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:85)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:38)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
    at com.domg.testrss.GetNewsHeadlinesUseCaseTest.parsing success(GetNewsHeadlinesUseCaseTest.kt:32)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:570)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.lambda$evaluate$0(SandboxTestRunner.java:278)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.Sandbox.lambda$runOnMainThread$0(Sandbox.java:89)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.ShadowWrangler.classInitializing(ShadowWrangler.java:181)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.RobolectricInternals.classInitializing(RobolectricInternals.java:21)
    at android.text.TextUtils.<clinit>(TextUtils.java)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.$$robo$$android_text_SpannableStringBuilder$__constructor__(SpannableStringBuilder.java:61)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.<init>(SpannableStringBuilder.java)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.<init>(SpannableStringBuilder.java)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.<init>(SpannableStringBuilder.java)
    at android.text.HtmlToSpannedConverter.$$robo$$android_text_HtmlToSpannedConverter$__constructor__(Html.java:425)
    at android.text.HtmlToSpannedConverter.<init>(Html.java)
    at android.text.Html.$$robo$$android_text_Html$fromHtml(Html.java:135)
    at android.text.Html.fromHtml(Html.java)
    at android.text.Html.$$robo$$android_text_Html$fromHtml(Html.java:101)
    at android.text.Html.fromHtml(Html.java)
    at androidx.core.text.HtmlCompat.fromHtml(HtmlCompat.java:150)
    at com.domg.testrss.domain.usecase.GetNewsHeadlinesUseCase.convertHtml(GetNewsHeadlinesUseCase.kt:162)
    at com.domg.testrss.domain.usecase.GetNewsHeadlinesUseCase.convertXmlToJson(GetNewsHeadlinesUseCase.kt:80)
    at com.domg.testrss.domain.usecase.GetNewsHeadlinesUseCase.execute(GetNewsHeadlinesUseCase.kt:35)
    at com.domg.testrss.GetNewsHeadlinesUseCaseTest$parsing success$1.invokeSuspend(GetNewsHeadlinesUseCaseTest.kt:33)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:279)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:85)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:38)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
    at com.domg.testrss.GetNewsHeadlinesUseCaseTest.parsing success(GetNewsHeadlinesUseCaseTest.kt:32)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.RobolectricInternals.performStaticInitialization(RobolectricInternals.java:61)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.ShadowWrangler.classInitializing(ShadowWrangler.java:178)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLegacyAssetManager.getAndResolve(ShadowLegacyAssetManager.java:1019)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLegacyAssetManager.getResourceText(ShadowLegacyAssetManager.java:285)
    at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceText(AssetManager.java)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:225)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:313)
    at android.text.TextUtils.__staticInitializer__(TextUtils.java:1704)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.RobolectricInternals.performStaticInitialization(RobolectricInternals.java:61)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.ShadowWrangler.classInitializing(ShadowWrangler.java:178)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.RobolectricInternals.classInitializing(RobolectricInternals.java:21)
    at android.text.TextUtils.<clinit>(TextUtils.java)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.__constructor__(SpannableStringBuilder.java:61)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.<init>(SpannableStringBuilder.java)
    at android.text.HtmlToSpannedConverter.__constructor__(Html.java:425)
    at android.text.HtmlToSpannedConverter.<init>(Html.java)
    at android.text.Html.fromHtml(Html.java:135)
    at android.text.Html.fromHtml(Html.java:101)
    at androidx.core.text.HtmlCompat.fromHtml(HtmlCompat.java:150)
    at com.domg.testrss.domain.usecase.GetNewsHeadlinesUseCase.convertHtml(GetNewsHeadlinesUseCase.kt:162)
    at com.domg.testrss.domain.usecase.GetNewsHeadlinesUseCase.convertXmlToJson(GetNewsHeadlinesUseCase.kt:80)
    at com.domg.testrss.domain.usecase.GetNewsHeadlinesUseCase.execute(GetNewsHeadlinesUseCase.kt:35)
    at com.domg.testrss.GetNewsHeadlinesUseCaseTest$parsing success$1.invokeSuspend(GetNewsHeadlinesUseCaseTest.kt:33)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:279)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:85)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:38)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
    at com.domg.testrss.GetNewsHeadlinesUseCaseTest.parsing success(GetNewsHeadlinesUseCaseTest.kt:32)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have discovered a solution. Add the following to the `android` section of the **module** `build.gradle`:

```
    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }
    }
```

According to [documentation](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/3.0/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.TestOptions.UnitTestOptions.html), setting this to true will allow a unit test "to use Android resources, assets, and manifests" by "perform[ing] resource, asset, and manifest merging before running your unit tests."

Once I added this as described above, the exceptions stopped and my unit tests invoking `HtmlCompat` were able to complete.